# Probabilty Independent 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

5. Events A and B are independent. Suppose event A occurs with probability $0.41$ and event B occurs with probability $ 0.40$.

a.  If event A or event B occurs, what is the probability that A occurs?

b.  If event B occurs, what is the probability that A does not occur?

Round your answers to at least two decimal places.

My try
a. $$\begin{split}P(A\mid A\cup B) &=P(A\cap (A\cup B))/P(A\cup B)\\ &=P(A)/P(A\cup B)\\ & =0.41/(0.41+0.40-(0.41*0.40))\\& =0.42\text{ (Correct to 2 decimal place)}\end{split}$$

b. $$\begin{split}P( A^\complement \mid B) &=P(A^\complement)\\ &=1-0.42\\ &=0.58\end{split}$$
Is my answer correct?

Comment: For $(b)$ did you mean to put $1-0.41=0.59$?

Comment: No I calculate it 1- the answer from A, am I wrong?

Comment: $P(A^c)=1-P(A)$  where $P(A)$ was given in the problem statement and has nothing to with part $(a)$

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for a: the logic is okay, but the calculations went awry. $$0.41/(0.41+0.40-0.41\cdot0.40)~{=0.41/0.646\\ \approx 0.63}$$

And for b: you used $0.42$ instead of $0.41$.

Comment: ohhh I see...Thanks